# Fade out when other list items are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

Earlier this week I was using a tutorial to achieve something similar, but I have decided to strip it down to a basic functionality. I want the user to be able to click on the bottle they want to know about and a content opens up. But if a person does not click the X and instead clicks on other bottles, it should fade out the current content and then show the newly clicked one.

My knowledge of J Query is limited, so I know I am using a longer technique by targeting each one by their id. I would love a more structured shorter version if someone can show it to me.

But based on my knowledge this is what I could construct.

HTML

```
    <div id="two" class="colorbottle">
    <img src="images/2.png">
    </div>



    <div id="three" class="colorbottle">
    <img src="images/3.png">
    </div>



    <div id="four" class="colorbottle">
    <img src="images/4.png">
    </div>

    <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="ei_descr" id="onedescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>

        <h2>Gary</h2>
        <h3>Vocals</h3>
        <p>
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my
        entire soul, like these sweet mornings of
        spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
        </p>
        <p>
        I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
        this spot, which was created for the bliss of
        souls like mine.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="ei_descr" id="twodescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>

        <h2>Gary</h2>
        <h3>Vocals</h3>
        <p>
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my
        entire soul, like these sweet mornings of
        spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
        </p>
        <p>
        I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
        this spot, which was created for the bliss of
        souls like mine.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="ei_descr" id="threedescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>
        <h2>Gary</h2>
        <h3>Vocals</h3>
        <p>
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my
        entire soul, like these sweet mornings of
        spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
        </p>
        <p>
        I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
        this spot, which was created for the bliss of
        souls like mine.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="ei_descr" id="fourdescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>

        <h2>Gary</h2>
        <h3>Vocals</h3>
        <p>
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my
        entire soul, like these sweet mornings of
        spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
        </p>
        <p>
        I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in
        this spot, which was created for the bliss of
        souls like mine.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   $(".colorbottle").click(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(".colorbottle.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");        
    }
});


$("#one").click(function() {

    $("#onedescr").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
    $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});

})

$(".contact_close").click(function() { 
$(".ei_descr").fadeOut("slow"); 
$(".colorbottle").animate({opacity:1});

 });


$("#two").click(function() {
    $("#twodescr").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
    $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});

})

   $("#three").click(function() {
    $("#threedescr").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
            $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});

})

$("#four").click(function() {
    $("#fourdescr").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
            $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});

})

});
```

Right now all it does is, fade in the one that is clicked, and makes the other bottles transparent.
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqn2sk5/)

Thanks

Comment: The CSS need adjustment, btw try [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqn2sk5/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use html `data-` **attribute** to store the id of div which needs to be shown on click of bottle div:

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapcraft">
    <div id="one" class="colorbottle" data-id="onedescr">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/v8n2hv.png">
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="colorbottle" data-id="twodescr">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/v8n2hv.png">
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="colorbottle" data-id="threedescr">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/v8n2hv.png">
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="colorbottle" data-id="fourdescr">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/v8n2hv.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
<div class="ei_descr" id="onedescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>
     <h2>Gary</h2>

     <h3>Vocals</h3>

    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
    <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div>
<div class="ei_descr" id="twodescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>
     <h2>Gary</h2>

     <h3>Vocals</h3>

    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
    <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div>
<div class="ei_descr" id="threedescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>
     <h2>Gary</h2>

     <h3>Vocals</h3>

    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
    <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div>
<div class="ei_descr" id="fourdescr">
    <div class="contact_close">X</div>
     <h2>Gary</h2>

     <h3>Vocals</h3>

    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
    <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div>
```

### JQUERY:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".colorbottle").click(function () {
         if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
             $(".colorbottle.selected").removeClass("selected");
             $(this).addClass("selected");
             $(".ei_descr").fadeOut(1000);
             $('#' + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn(1000);
             $(".colorbottle").not(".selected").animate({
                 opacity: 0.2
             });
             $(".selected").animate({
                 opacity: 1
             });
         }
     });

 });
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqn2sk5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="two" class="colorbottle" onlick = "goto('two')">

    <img src="images/2.png">
    </div>



    <div id="three" class="colorbottle" onlick = "goto('three')">
    <img src="images/3.png">
    </div>



    <div id="four" class="colorbottle" onlick = "goto('four')">
    <img src="images/4.png">
    </div>


    <script>
function goto(id){
    $("#"+id+"descr").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
    $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});
}
<script>
```

Comment: I am not able to execute what you have suggested, does the script work with my existing script or without it, either way I am not sure how it works. Thanks though..

Comment: Use @Ehsan Sajjad answer, his is much better

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell the descriptions to fadeout on click and only fadein the one you clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqn2sk5/5/

```
$('.ei_descr').fadeOut();
$('#'+this.id+'descr').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below simplification code and working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqn2sk5/7/)

```
   $(".colorbottle").click(function () {
        $(".colorbottle").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        var popupId= $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#"+popupId).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".colorbottle").not( ".selected").animate({opacity:0.2});
        $(".selected").animate({opacity:1});
    });

     $(".contact_close").click(function() { 
       $(".ei_descr").fadeOut("slow"); 
       $(".colorbottle").animate({opacity:1});
    });
```

Also, you need to rename the id of 4 bottles div (for example bootle1 as follows)

```
<div id="b_onedescr" class="colorbottle">
```

instead of

```
<div id="one" class="colorbottle">
```